# XML Serialization Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an issue with the Namespaces that my code is producing. What I'd Like is the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClassToSerialize Type="Customer" Name="Some Name" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.123.org/namespace C:\Schema\ClassToSerialize.xsd" 
xmlns:Test="http://www.Test.org/" xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace">
  <Address>
    <Line1>Addr1</Line1>
    <Line2>Addr2</Line2>
  </Address>
</ClassToSerialize>
```

What I'm getting is this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClassToSerialize xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.123.org/namespace C:\Schema\ClassToSerialize.xsd"
 xmlns:Test="http://www.Test.org/" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace" Type="Customer" Name="Some Name">
  <Address>
    <Line1>Addr1</Line1>
    <Line2>Addr2</Line2>
  </Address>
</ClassToSerialize>
```

Main differences are:

```
1. xmlns:schemaLocation= needs to be xsi:schemaLocation=
2. xmlns:xmlns= needs to be xmlns=
3. Attributes Order, I would prefer the Attributes to be presented before the namespace attributes (This is not a big Issue, just nice to have)
```

Currently what I am doing is to replace the values in the serialized string in 1 & 2 above with the values I want, a hack that works but i suspect there is a way to modify the namespace code to do this at that point?

Here is the code I am using, how can i change GetNameSpace() to do what I need in points 1 & 2, also can i re-order the attributes?:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassToSerialize myInstance = new ClassToSerialize();
        myInstance.Type = "Customer";
        myInstance.Name = "Some Name";
        myInstance.AddressField = new Address("Addr1", "Addr2");

        String sString = SerializeObject<ClassToSerialize>(myInstance, GetNameSpace());

        //Hack to achieve what I want from namespaces
        sString = sString.Replace("xmlns:schemaLocation=", "xsi:schemaLocation=");
        sString = sString.Replace("xmlns:xmlns=", "xmlns=");
    }

    private XmlSerializerNamespaces GetNameSpace()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces xsNS = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        xsNS.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        xsNS.Add("xmlns", "http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace");
        xsNS.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.123.org/namespace C:\\Schema\\ClassToSerialize.xsd");
        xsNS.Add("Test", "http://www.Test.org/");

        return xsNS;
    }

    public static string SerializeObject<X>(X toSerialize, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace)
    {
        string strRetVal = "";
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
            StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

            using (StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize, xmlNameSpace);
                strRetVal = writer.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strError = ex.ToString();
        }

        return strRetVal;
    }
}

public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}

    public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Address")]
    public Address AddressField { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [XmlElement, DefaultValue("")]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement, DefaultValue("")]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    public Address()
    {

    }

    public Address(string L1, string L2)
    {
        Line1 = L1;
        Line2 = L2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `schemaLocation` is not a namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can add `xsi:schemaLocation` by adding a synthetic property along the lines of the answer in [How to add xsi schemalocation to root c # object XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809868/how-to-add-xsi-schemalocation-to-root-c-object-xmlserializer/18747195#18747195) -- but use a property instead of a field.  If you use a field you will actually add to the footprint of your class in memory.
2. To define a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace"`, you can apply [`[XmlRoot("ClassToSerialize", Namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your `ClassToSerialize` or [allocate an `XmlRootAttribute` override and pass it to the `XmlSerializer` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736882/can-i-specify-xmlroot-via-code-instead-of-attributes).  Be sure to cache the serializer if you do the latter.
3. Other than implementing [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), which is somewhat burdensome, I don't know if it's possible to control the attribute order with `XmlSerializer`.  However, the XML specification states ["the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags), so I recommend not worrying about it.

Thus the following should do the trick.  Note I moved your `GetNameSpace()` inside `ClassToSerialize` and renamed it `GetAdditionalNamespaces()`:

```
[XmlRoot("ClassToSerialize", Namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/namespace")]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces GetAdditionalNamespaces()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces xsNS = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        xsNS.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        xsNS.Add("Test", "http://www.Test.org/");

        return xsNS;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string XSDSchemaLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return "http://www.123.org/namespace C:\\Schema\\ClassToSerialize.xsd";
        }
        set
        {
            // Do nothing - fake property.
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Address")]
    public Address AddressField { get; set; }
}
```