# Serialize XML from C# class, need to set namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm having trouble getting my top-level element to look exactly like this using the XmlSerializer (and C# attributes):

```
<rootObject xmlns="http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema1.xsd">
    <otherSerializedObjects />
</rootObject>
```

Currently, the closest I've gotten is this:

```
<rootObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    d1p1:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema1.xsd" 
    xmlns:d1p1="xsi" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema">
    <otherSerializedObjects />
</rootObject>
```

C#

```
[XmlRoot("rootObject", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema")]
public class RootObject
{
    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "xsi")]
    public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public Object[] OtherSerializedObjects { get; set; }

    public RootObject()
    {
        OtherSerializedObjects = new Object[]{};
    }
}   

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootObject = new RootObject
        {
            SchemaLocation = "http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema1.xsd",
            OtherSerializedObjects = new object[]{}
        };

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, rootObject);
        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? How close have you gotten? What specifically does "having trouble" mean?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530334/xml-serialization-namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the [`[XmlAttribute(Namespace=X)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your `schemaLocation` field/property needs to have the *full* namespace for the value of *`X`*, not the local namespace shortcut.  Incidentally, this can be a property rather than a field.  Using a field for this purpose wastes memory.

Secondly, to eliminate the standard `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`, use an [`XmlSerializer.Serialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload where you pass in an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` with just the namespaces you want.

Thus:

```
[XmlRoot("rootObject", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema")]
public class RootObject
{
    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces GetAdditionalNamespaces()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces xsNS = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();


        xsNS.Add("", "http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema");
        xsNS.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        return xsNS;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string XSDSchemaLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return "http://www.example.com/xmlschemas/nonStandardSchema1.xsd";
        }
        set
        {
            // Do nothing - fake property.
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public Object[] OtherSerializedObjects { get; set; }

    public RootObject()
    {
        OtherSerializedObjects = new Object[]{};
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
        var rootObject = new RootObject
        {
            OtherSerializedObjects = new object[]{}
        };

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var ns = RootObject.GetAdditionalNamespaces();

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, rootObject, ns);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RR2YY6).

Comment: (Looking back at older questions) - this was the right answer, it worked as I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Namespace needs to be the entire namespace, not the shortened version.

```
[XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
```

In my testing it automatically used `xsi`.